# How do I virtualize a physical machine, and be able to put the image back on the real machine?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, virtual-machine, virtualization

Can I convert a physical machine running Windows (XP, 7, etc) to an exact copy  virtual machine, make modifications on it and be able to put it back on the physical machine if I need it?

**The OP adds in comment**

A software solution to my mind should have an agent that installs the right vm drivers in the windows machine, and then sets them default before migrating the hdd to the vm image. So technically is possible

Comment: There are dozens upon dozens of both paid and free software that does this.  What have you tried?

Comment: @Ramhound What should I try ?

Comment: I will go ahead and repeat my question.  What have you tried?

Comment: @Ramhound I usually make a hard image / and then if things go wrong revert to that image, I use Clonezila, I used sometime ago Acronis and Norton Ghost. But on the virtual machine conversion don't know where to start, the hdd conversion to an image is useless, I converted sometimes ago a linux machine for ESXi, but I don't know if it works for Windows and how am I supposed to convert it back if I want to make it work on the machine again.

Comment: Acronis sells software that does what you need.

Comment: AT Ramhound. Dozens and Dozens of both paid and free software.. If you think there is, how about you also tell him about free software that does it(not just creating and restoring images, but running it on a VM.. dozens of paid and free software for that). And since you think it's so easy, why don't you tell him about a few of the dozens of free software you have used to make an image run on a VM.

Comment: AT Ramhound. You say dozens and dozens , and the one single software you mention is A)Paid Software and B) You repeat to him in comment that he should use Acronis, 10 minutes AFTER he has commented that he tried Acronis and had problems.  Have you even done what you are implying is so easy. And if so, why don't you address the issues he is having

Comment: @EduardFlorinescu I have once created an image with macrium reflect, converted it into a VHD file with an option within Macrium Reflect.  Tried to run the VHD failed. There is software from vmware that can treat a VHD but I didn't get round to completing trying it, it involved a client and a server setup just to convert the vhd or vhdk into an ok one.   I have heard that sysprep can help too, i'm not sure if that's an alternative.

Comment: And i've heard of an option in Acronis that can make windows run on a motherboard with a different chipset . Maybe that option will make it run on a VM too. You could try that option.

Comment: so look into sysprep, look into that acronis option I have heard of, that I mentioned,  and here is the vmware thing .. vmware [center] converter..  . that may treat the image https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/evalcenter?p=converter   so you could try that and do report back  with an @ to me 'cos i'm interested in that too

Comment: This question is too General for effective answers.  Do you have a specific use case in mind? i.e a particular OS, to be converted and used with a particular hyper-visor, with what infrastructure you will use to support this.  If you consider this process at the start then you could use Hyper-V and `VHD`s.  Windows can boot `VHD` on physical and virtual.  However you may be limited with how you present your storage devices and their will be other limitation on hardware support.  I've used `P2V`  (Physical to Virtual) and `V2P' modifying each between hosts so it can be done, but why?

Comment: @albal Windows is the OS, did you read the question and comments before down-voting,

Answer (score 0):

Booting a Windows system on a machine which is different than the one it was installed on is not a good idea: First, it kills the activation. Second, it might not boot because the chipset is different and the drivers might crash. Third, if it boots, it will reinstall most system drivers, which might make it fail on the real machine.

So: Yes, it is possible to make a virtual machine out of a real one (which boils down to "make an image of the physical hard disk"), change it, and write it back to the real machine. Booting it, if it contains Windows, is not. (With Linux, it usually is not a problem.)

Comment: A software solution to my mind should have an agent that installs the right vm drivers in the windows machine, and then sets them default before migrating the hdd to the vm image.

So technically is possible

Answer (score 0):

If using vmware preload vmware tools before capturing the image.
XP maybe the trickiest but it can be done.

In the Device Manager, open **IDE/ATAPI controllers**

```
  Then **properties**
  Then **Driver**
  **Update driver**
  then **Browse manually**.
```

Then select **Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer**

```
  Uncheck **show compatible hardware**,
  then find **Standard IDE/ATAPI controller**
  on the left and **Standard Dual Channel PCI IDE controller**
  on the right.
  Repeat for each device under **IDE/ATAPI controllers**
```

Clonezilla the physical to and image.

1. create a blank VM with a hdd big enough to receive the image.
2. Attach the hdd with the image on it to the VM.
3. Boot the VM, but activate boot from CD or ISO and connect to a clonezilla ISO.
4. Restore the image
5. Disconnect the ISO
6. Reboot and if the hardware incompatibilities aren't too bad it should boot.

Transferring back to real hardware.

1. Boot VM from clonezilla ISO/CD
2. back up to external hdd
3. Boot physical PC with Clonezilla DVD/USB(Press F9 and select boot from CD)
4. Restore the image
5. Reboot
6. Assuming hardware compatibility hasn't changed it should work.

You can also substitute a Windows PE bootable ISO and using imagex instead of clonezilla.

Comment: -1  Very unlikely what you describe will get a HDD image running on a VM.  You haven't said what to create a VM in.  Virtualbox.  Vmware.. It may make a difference.. And file file extension this file is going to be i norder to run on the VM.   Have you ever even tried doing it? All you're writing there is a dummy guide for how to create and restore images.

Comment: A virtual machine is rather like different hardware, to a physical machine.. Obviously you can run software in a VM  that creates an image,  You say "Boot physical PC with Clonzzilla" what on earth are you talking about. You  boot a physical PC by walking up to it and pushing a button.. And he wants to load a HDD into a virtual machine and boot a VIRTUAL machine..that is an image of the physical one. Even Virtual machine software doesn't boot physical machines, it's a nonsense what you wrote, li saying you drove to work on your felt tip pen.  And  ISO image..

Comment: @barlop I think where he says ISO he means the Clonezilla ISO/CD, I agree with you that even if you restore the image on the virtual machine and then boot there are big chances for windows to have problems booting...

Comment: And you write "Boot VM from Clone Zilla"  AGAIN- What on earth are you talking about.  Maybe you mean clonezilla from VM. But anyhow, this does not address the core of his problem

Comment: @EduardFlorinescu  Maybe infinitely more than a big chance of failure- I would like to see even one case of it just booting up fully. It may even be 100% chance that it won't work! (without treating windows / the image fully beforehand). What that treatment is, is your essential question.

Comment: @barlop "Boot physical PC with clonezilla"  I will explain.  Turn PC on.  Eject DVD drive and place Clonezilla CD/DVD in tray and close, or insert clonezilla bootable USB stick.  Press F9 or whatever your boot from alternative device key.  From the boot menu select either the CD/DVD drive or USB bootable device depending on which one you inserted.

Comment: @barlop  **You haven't said what to create a VM in. Virtualbox. Vmware**  This procedure works for both with only minor differences.  Sure the emulated hardware is different.  I am assuming we are dealing with intelligent people and skipping or being general because a full step by step is like 10 pages.

Comment: Most VM systems like VMware and virtualbox emulate hardware that is old enough that windows has drivers for it.

Comment: @cybernard  I agree with you that stating how to create a virtual machine it doesn't matter whether it's virtualbox or vmware.. and I agree we are dealing with intelligent people.. I wasn't referring to creating a virtual machine. But when it comes to converting the virtual machine image to make it suitable to be written to a hard drive and run non-virtually, then it may make a difference, for example, Vmware has a program called vmware converter.. I am not aware of a virtualbox equivalent. Or whether vmware converter can be applied to a file from virtualbox(i'd guess not).

Comment: @cybernard I've removed the -1 'cos it's good that you have now added about IDE/ATAPI  (so at least attempting to treat the image).. I don't know if it'd be enough treatment, it'd be interesting to see if that treats it sufficiently.  I recall reading once that when moving a HDD between motheboards of different chipsets, you have to deal with a HAL issue.. like replacing the HAL with something generic

Comment: @barlop  I have used vmware converter and the version I used had made it very difficult to use.  You need another machine beside the VMware box and the physical machine to act as an intermediary.  I have added information on pre-treating the physical machine.

Comment: @barlop  I have moved several XP images to different motherboards with different chipsets this way.  It was an Intel to Intel move so Intel to AMD or vice versa may be trickery.  I have discovered through **much** trial and error that the hard drive drivers are the Achilles heel and once those are addressed windows can plug and play new drivers or use generic ones for the rest.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26712/discussion-between-barlop-and-cybernard).

Comment: Why would Windows XP be the trickiest?  It all depends on the compatibility of hardware between the physical and virtual host.  With windows running sysprep before cold-cloning would be good.  The disk format issue, this is the easy part - there are plenty of tools to convert between all the different disk formats and as a last resort there is always RAW.

Comment: @albal It is the trickiest because its driver database is very small compared to Win Vista and newer.  Heck, it can't even handle AHCI without help.   They have stopped updating it so there will never be new drivers to support further advances in technology.

Comment: @cybernard but that is not an issue of P2V - the OP wants to do P2V then V2P back to the same hardware

Comment: @albal it's better to put comments in the chat link that the comment section spawned. As the way the people that run the site like it, is not numerous comments, sometimes they delete comments, less so if they're in chat. So a chat link in the comments is a good place to put extended discussion. Sometimes they move comments to chat, but may as well put them there when the chat link is spawned.